# Stuck with SQL query in Symfony 4

Tags: sql, symfony

I try to list the 3 most liked user in a table.

Here is the entitys that i have :

$User, $Post, $PostLike.

The user can aswer to a question by posting a $Post, each post can be like or dislike by users.

In $Post i have : the User can posted, the question the post is answering.
In $PostLike i have : The User that liked or disliked, the Post, and a bolean (1 if like,0 for dislike)

So i think i can get all the PostLike where the bolean == 1 then group them by $Post then Groupe the result by User and get the length of all Like or Dislike an user get.

I'm stuck with the sql query.

Anyone can help me please?

Here's the entity code :

```
class StackUser
{

private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}
}
```

.

```
class Post
{

private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $ThePostHimself;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PostLike", mappedBy="Post")
 */
private $postLikes;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->postLikes = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUser(): ?User
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser(?User $user): self
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

public function getThePostHimself(): ?string
{
    return $this->ThePostHimself;
}

public function setThePostHimself(string $ThePostHimself): self
{
    $this->ThePostHimself = $ThePostHimself;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|PostLike[]
 */
public function getPostLikes(): Collection
{
    return $this->postLikes;
}

public function addPostLike(PostLike $postLike): self
{
    if (!$this->postLikes->contains($postLike)) {
        $this->postLikes[] = $postLike;
        $postLike->addPost($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removePostLike(PostLike $postLike): self
{
    if ($this->postLikes->contains($postLike)) {
        $this->postLikes->removeElement($postLike);
        $postLike->removePost($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

.

```
class PostLike
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $LikeDislike;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post",    inversedBy="postLikes")
 */
private $Post;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->Post = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getLikeDislike(): ?bool
{
    return $this->LikeDislike;
}

public function setLikeDislike(bool $LikeDislike): self
{
    $this->LikeDislike = $LikeDislike;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Post[]
 */
public function getPost(): Collection
{
    return $this->Post;
}

public function addPost(Post $post): self
{
    if (!$this->Post->contains($post)) {
        $this->Post[] = $post;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removePost(Post $post): self
{
    if ($this->Post->contains($post)) {
        $this->Post->removeElement($post);
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried some sql query :

        public function getTopLikeUser(){
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
                'SELECT a
                 FROM App\Entity\PostLike aL
                 WHERE aL.likeDislike = "1"
                 GROUP BY aL.post
                 GROUP BY aL.post.user 
                 LIMIT "3"
                 ORDER BY DESC'                                        
        );
        return $query->execute();
    }